# AIR Native process Error

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I try to launch a programm with NativeProcess on Mac.

```
pathEV="/Applications/MyFolder/MyAppOSX.app"
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var fileEV:File = new File();
fileEV=fileEV.resolvePath(pathEV);
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = fileEV;
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

But this error appear:
Error #3214: NativeProcessStartupInfo.executable does not specify a valid executable file

Can you help me to solve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it yet, but I assume you'd need to run `open` with the path to your application as a parameter, like this:

```
pathEV:String="/Applications/MyFolder/MyAppOSX.app"
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
var fileEV:File = new File();
fileEV=fileEV.resolvePath( '/usr/bin/open' );
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = Vector.<String>([pathEV]);
nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = fileEV;
var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

And yes, this definitely needs `extendedDesktop` rights

FYI: The Vector shizzle is correct, I use it to convert the array to Vector, not as a constructor function

[Here's an explanation how to launch `.app` files from the terminal](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to add `<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>` to your manifest file?

Also, I believe[.app is not an executable](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html).  Its actually just an application bundle within which exists the actual executable.  Try pointing to `/bin/ls` first to make sure all else is OK and then dig inside the .app folder to find your executable.

Comment: I also added <supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles> to my manifest file. On MacOs .app is like an executable, try to test your idea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a nativeProcess? Why not just use fileEV.openWithDefaultApplication() ?